# MVCControlsToolkit and Validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

Today I installed the `MVC3ControlsToolkit` from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/MVC3ControlsToolkit), and proceeded to add a a `DateTimeFor` control to a Scaffolding generated page. I only changed one line of code, but the page was no longer visible, and an exception was thrown, saying validation was happening twice.

If I set `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` to false in my `Web.config`, I can view the page. Funny thing is that if I restore the page to it's previous state (ie. default config) the error persists.

The error I get is: *"Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: required"*

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it.